# declare map with key value pairs in one operation

Tags: go

Is it possible to declare a map with key value pairs?

Something like this

```
var env map[string]int{
    "key0": 10,
    "key1": 398
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can declare a map with name value pairs. You can use a [variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variable_declarations) with a [map composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals):

```
var env = map[string]int{
   "key0": 10,
   "key1": 398,
}
```

or a [short variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations) with the composite literal:

```
env := map[string]int{
   "key0": 10,
   "key1": 398,
}
```

The short variable declaration can only be used in a function. The variable declaration can be used in functions and at package level.

Also note the added "," following the 398.

Answer (score 4):

It is, but you need to add an extra '`,`' and, in your case, a `=` (`var env = map...`) .

Here is an example from "[Go maps in action](http://blog.golang.org/go-maps-in-action)":

```
commits := map[string]int{
    "rsc": 3711,
    "r":   2138,
    "gri": 1908,
    "adg": 912,
}
```

Without the final ',', you get:

```
syntax error: need trailing comma before newline in composite literal
```

---

Note with Go 1.5 (August 2015), you will be able to use literal for map *key* (and not just for map values), in the case of a map literal.
See [review 2591](https://go-review.googlesource.com/#/c/2591/) and [commit 7727dee](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/7727dee44565bed441c9fc09a2e2441ecd6b9fe7).

```
map[string]Point{"orig": {0, 0}}    // same as map[string]Point{"orig": Point{0, 0}}
map[Point]string{{0, 0}: "orig"}    // same as map[Point]string{Point{0, 0}: "orig"}
```

Comment: With your example I get this `non-declaration statement outside function body` .. I'm declaring the map directly in a package as a "global" var